# How to remove junk characters from a file using bash script

Tags: python

I have the output in a file like this which has some junk characters.
Please let me know how do we remove or get rid of these junk characters using bash script.

KiB Mem :(B[m[39;49m[1m 20395700 (B[m[39;49mtotal,(B[m[39;49m[1m 14088032 (B[m[39;49mfree,(B[m[39;49m[1m  2593300 (B[m[39;49mused,(B[m[39;49m[1m  3714368 (B[m[39;49mbuff/cache(B[m[39;49m(B[m[39;49m[K
KiB Swap:(B[m[39;49m[1m 10461180 (B[m[39;49mtotal,(B[m[39;49m[1m 10461180 (B[m[39;49mfree,(B[m[39;49m[1m        0 (B[m[39;49mused.(B[m[39;49m[1m 16599764 (B[m[39;49mavail Mem (B[m[39;49m(B[m[39;49m[K
KiB Mem :(B[m[39;49m[1m 20395700 (B[m[39;49mtotal,(B[m[39;49m[1m 14088188 (B[m[39;49mfree,(B[m[39;49m[1m  2592956 (B[m[39;49mused,(B[m[39;49m[1m  3714556 (B[m[39;49mbuff/cache(B[m[39;49m(B[m[39;49m[K
KiB Swap:(B[m[39;49m[1m 10461180 (B[m[39;49mtotal,(B[m[39;49m[1m 10461180 (B[m[39;49mfree,(B[m[39;49m[1m        0 (B[m[39;49mused.(B[m[39;49m[1m 16600252 (B[m[39;49mavail Mem (B[m[39;49m(B[m[39;49m[K

Comment: that "junk" is called [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: How do we do the same in bash script